# Snubbing DCM (nonsynchronous) Buck converter

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, snubber, ringing

**FINAL UPDATE:**

I've posted an outcome report below. I'm very satisfied with how this has come out and I learned a lot in the process. More details and before/after shots in the answer below. Thanks to @Andy and @winny for their help and encouragement :)

Just a note to help search, the board used here is colloquially known as the "Fake LM2596 eBay buck converter". The chip behaves like an LM2576 (52kHz switching frequency instead of 150kHz) although it possibly lacks the protection circuitry.

---

I'm working with an LM2576-based buck converter as a **learning** project. Basically I've made a $0.99 eBay buck into a highly-affordable if somewhat less flexible demo board :)

[image]

The LM2576 enters discontinuous conduction mode (DCM) at light loads (<500mA
or so), and when it does, it exhibits vigorous ringing on the switch node
when the diode turns off, the residual energy in the inductor bouncing back-and-forth between the inductor and the diode capacitance:

[image]

The datasheet states this is nothing to worry about, but that it can be addressed with an RC snubber across the inductor if desired. I understand most folks wouldn't bother with it, but since this is a learning project and my first chance to design a real-life snubber, I want to do the best I can and learn as much as possible for future snubbing challenges.

Also, the ringing counts as EMI in my world, and it does couple to the output:

[image]

I've done a lot of research on snubbers, six distinct sources including Rudy
Severns' eBook and all the application notes (and a master's thesis) I could find.
Because I'm doing this as a learning project, I want to master the concepts and
procedure in general, not just get a solution good enough for a particular
application.

Here's the schematic (the actual diode is marked SS34, the SS3P5 is the closest available LTspice model):

[image]

And here's the board layout:

[image]

reverse side mirror-imaged for easier through-hole matching:

[image]

By following the prescribed procedure (detailed below), I get the values 1nF
and 220R. These tame the ringing substantially:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

I installed a pot in the resistor position and discovered 430Ω provides maximal damping with a 1nF (C0G) cap.

With the optimal resistor in place, I was able to do better:

[image]

---

But they don't critically damp the ringing, which is what was indicated in [1] Todd at least and what I was after.

I've found on simulation that I can achieve critical damping (or something
quite close) with the values 8.6nF and 350R.

[image]

So I'm wondering why the sources I found all pretty much agree, but all give me lower values than what seems to be called for.

I have a couple hypotheses:

1. **Mine is a special case.** Most of the sources use synchronous buck converters in their example. These have a larger capacitance and much lower inductance. The formulas don't work when the situation is reversed. (In my case, L=47uH, C=100pF.)
2. **Nobody wants to snub to critical damping.** In my case, the energy to be snubbed is small (single digit mW), in the more common cases, the designer is making a significant trade-off against efficiency and a couple wiggles left on the waveform is perfectly acceptable.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm seeing?

One anomaly I've noticed is that all the sources say the RC time constant of the snubber should be short compared to switching frequency but long compared to rise time of waveform to be snubbed. The values I got (1nF, 220R) have a time constant almost the same as the rise time of the ringing (~200ns).

(**Update:** I later realized I was measuring the rise time *after* installing the snubber. A close measurement of the unsnubbed circuit revealed a rise time of 116ns and the final snubber R value produced an RC of 426ns. This roughly 4x \$\tau\$ value seemed to be "bigger enough" :)

---

Prescribed procedure

1. Add capacitance across switch node until ringing frequency is reduced to 1/3 original value (some say 1/2). This determines original C is 1/8th of added value (total C is 9 times original, sqrt(9)=3).
2. Calculate characteristic impedance of new LC tank, sqrt(L/C). Use resistor of this value.

   On a close second reading, I discovered the sources disagree on which values to use for the characteristic impedance calculation. [1] Todd recommends using the *original* \$C_{parasitic}\$. Another uses the new total \$C_{parasitic} + C_{snubber}\$. The optimal value I found is nearly right in the middle of these two (209Ω < 430Ω < 670Ω).

Resources:

[1] [Todd, Philip C.; *Snubber Circuits: Theory, Design and Application*](http://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=http://www.deyisupport.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/13-107-00-00-00-00-74-81/slup100.pdf&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm3G1YGVs7LMsD-S9Xc6uIebsRO1aA&nossl=1&oi=scholarr)

Comment: I always go for 2 and make a reality check in spice how much power will be dissipated. If your LC frequency is too close to the switching frequency, this will waste a lot of power. Forced CCM comes to mind too.

Comment: @winny: I get 16mW for the original values and 53mW for the critically damped case. So I do see the power cost involved now that you mention it :)

Comment: Where are you measuring you voltage? Output of switch ripple always has that kind of waveform, this is why LC circuit is used to eliminate rippling that is supplied to output

Comment: @ArtūrasJonkus: The two scope shots are on the switch node.

Comment: That's nothing. Go for it!

Comment: Also, nice pigtail technique for probing!

Comment: @winny: Thanks! I learned that trick from W2AEW on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4q8geE5ef8 :) I use it all the time now on switchers.

Comment: @scanny You are welcome. Unless high voltage so 0805 or even 1206 isn't enough, I add critical RC over every switching component in my designs and remove if price is an issue and it makes no difference on EMC.

Comment: I am unimpressed that you wasted my time not saying up front it wasn't a real TI part - you lied and caused me to waste my time. Do not do this again if you want the respect from other EE users. If it's a fake then almost certainly it does have a MOSFET output (given also the slow speed) yet you insisted it used a BJT - you CANNOT know this. Consider yourself in the dog-house. In case you didn't realize, I am bloody angry at what you have done and expect an explanation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have lied all the way through about this being a genuine TI part when it's an ebay fake.

Comment: @Andyaka: I'm so sorry about that, it wasn't my intent to deceive, I was just assuming it was an LM2576 inside (it's marked LM2596) since it has that clock speed. I will be sure to mention that up top the next time. I apologize for putting you to any extra effort on account of my lapse :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically this is a non-problem. You don't need to do suppress the free-wheeling ringing due to the inductor and drain-source capacitance of the open-circuit MOSFET (more likely than the diode) in a buck converter because nothing bad happens if you leave it alone. The voltage in both polarities is never bigger than the voltage due to switching so the MOSFET cannot harmed by it.

It's totally different on a flyback converter of course but this is a non-synchronous buck converter.

Just regard it as a little bit of energy that could not make it's way to the output.

After-thought - if you were really clever you might be able to find a way of harnessing these oscillations and feed that energy back to the input capacitor. That would certainly be a step in the ecologicial right direction.

The device data sheet has this circuit for reducing output ripple by up to 10 times: -

[image]

The LC network will rely on the ESR of the capacitor added being as low as possible and quite probably if you are using "any old" capacitor in the Cout position (ref diagram above) then its ESR and ESL will be poor. TI are **not** recommending a snubber to reduce ripple!

Comment: Except for EMC.

Comment: The LM2576 uses a BJT (Darlington) for the switching, although I take your point. The ringing might not hurt the switch, but it does couple to the output (2.5MHz, about 15mV p-p). In my case, it's my first chance to design a real-live snubber, so I'm keen to make the best job of it I can and learn as much as possible from the exercise. I understand the question might be academic, but, well, I'm academizing at the moment :)

Comment: @winny - don't you think that the fast rising edges of the switcher cause much more EMI than the relatively slow moving ringing?

Comment: @scanny - a MOSFET that clamps the back emf instead of a diode will do the trick but then you have a synchronous buck converter. Adding a passive snubber can work but it also significantly lowers the efficiency of the buck conversion - each time the "transistor" hard switches on it dumps a finite amount of energy into the resistive part of the snubber thus you degrade the efficiency.

Comment: @scanny if you get output ripple problems due to the ringing then you probably need to consider how the hundred or so pF parasitic capacitance is managing to to shift the output voltage around to the tune of 15 mVp-p. This would be my objective. Maybe the output capacitor is not that good or maybe your scope probes are giving a false reading (very common in switchers).

Comment: @scanny - if you are relying on the 220 uF electrolytic to reduce switching ripple then think again - maybe add a 10 uF ceramic across it. Consider posting a schematic.

Comment: @AndyAka They sure do but the ringing is sometimes over the limit too and I prefer to capture the problem at the source.

Comment: @scanny post a schematic and screen shot of the ripple. It might also be very relevant to show the PCB layout.

Comment: Hi Andy, just updated question with schematic and layout, also new \$R_{snubber}\$ value I determined using a variable resistor in the R position.

Comment: TI recommend R1 to be between 1k and 5k. Yours is 330R. The DS also doesn't seem to mention anything about the 5.6 nF across R2 - is it there for a reason? The output waveform is dominated by the pulse and not the much smaller AC ripple - can you please confirm that the much smaller ripple is the noise that concerns you? Layout looks OK but exactly where and how are you probing?

Comment: The board came with R1=330, that's an interesting catch. The 5.6nF is not populated, apologies for that. It's a feed-forward cap that's used on the LM2596. I've updated the schematic. The output is measured with a 10x resistive probe (450R as tip, into 50R pass-thru at scope BNC). I must have left off the 50R pass-thru originally, because now it's more like 7mV p-p. I've added a scope shot with output against switch-node to show ringing
coupling.

Comment: Probably not a problem being 330 ohms. Probe earthing lead length is usually a problem in switchers of any type across a wide range of loads so what technique did you use?

Comment: Also, the self resonant frequency of the inductor is a big culprit. Can you recognize the inductor make?

Comment: Also I'm having problems with the scope shot. You say 7mVp-p (previously 20 mVp-p) but where on that waveform are you suggesting it is 7 mVp-p? The latest scope shot seems to imply to me that the whole waveform p-p is 20 mV making the ringing more like 1 mVp-p and decaying to uVp-p.

Comment: OK I can see the probe in one of your first pictures - it's fine!

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, you state that "this is a non-problem" as "The voltage in both polarities is never bigger than the voltage due to switching so the MOSFET cannot harmed by it". It is my understanding that this statement refers to ringing which is due to the buck converter running in discontinuous conduction mode (DCM) - which is the case discussed here. In contrast to that, switch node ringing can easily exceed the input voltage for a buck converter running in CCM or [a synchronous buck converter](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slpa010/slpa010.pdf) and thus may harm the MOSFET. Would you agree? Thanks.

Comment: @DanielK. I can't speak for every switching converter ever built but, in my experience, the peak value of the ringing (DCM) never exceeds the main voltage level being switched. For CCM, yes it can be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

**OUTCOME REPORT:**

Okay, I think I've sucked all the learning juice out of this exercise, thanks to @AndyAka and @winny for their help and encouragement :)

Here's before the snubber, switch-node in yellow, output in blue:

[image]

And here it is after:

[image]

The values I used were 1nF and 470R for anyone just looking for a recipe to try :)

My key takeaway interpretations are:

- Snubbing is to *improve* waveforms, not make them perfect. It's always a trade-off and getting to "tidy waveform" is going to cost more power/efficiency than it's worth.
- Snubbing is not an exact science; the analytics just get untenably complex. Be satisfied with the calculations getting you close, then simulate or solder in a variable resistor to get the rest of the way.
- Decide on a capacitor value, then tune in the resistor, letting the calculations guide your starting point. The resistor matching the characteristic impedance of the tank is what absorbs the energy, which is what stops the wiggles. So this step is where you achieve the optimal waveform. Some overshoot may remain; you're going to want to learn to live with that :)
- If you really can't live with the overshoot, you're going to need a bigger capacitor. The downside is that power dissipation (and consequent decrease in efficiency) scales proportional to the capacitor size. If you do change the capacitor, you'll need to tune in the R value again, but it probably won't change drastically.
- Do take the time to measure the rise time of the ringing waveform at the start. When comparing it to the RC (\$\tau\$) of the snubber, \$\tau > 3t_{rise}\$ is about minimum, 10x may be the upper limit. Mine was 4x and that worked fine.

Thanks again to @Andy and @winny, this was a really useful "lab" and I learned a lot :)

If there are any additional details that might be helpful let me know and I'll add them.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, you seem to have single handedly learned my second best EMC trick up my sleeve from 8 years of EMC compliance work so you have a bright future cut out for you :-)

Comment: I would just like to add that in my opinion the snubbing you have done does nothing to improve the EMI on the output - this is dominated by the main pulse being turned into a ramp-up and ramp-down - it has roughly the same rise and fall time as the minute-in-comparison wiggle due to inductor resonance with what is almost certainly a MOSFET (given that you were deceitful about the un-TI part used). Please scanny, don't play tricks like this again - I feel you went too far and I feel a little mugged by this and I have to down vote your question and this answer....

Comment: .... to show my concern at you deliberately hiding the true facts.

Comment: @Andyaka - I am so sorry about that, I had no intent to deceive, as far as I know the innards are actually an LM2576, I've found no difference in behavior, although of course you're right there's no real way to know. On page 14 of the LM25*96* datasheet (as this part is marked) mentions specifically [During DCM] "a small amount of energy can circulate between the inductor and the switch/diode parasitic capacitance", which is why I focused on the diode. But I guess I don't see the reason why it matters where the capacitance is coming from, the snubbing works the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: How can you say you had no intent to deceive when you clearly state in the amendment to your question that it runs at a vastly different speed. I'm not talking about this anymore.

Comment: @Andyaka - I'm sorry I've made you angry. I just got to thinking it was an LM2576 inside (cheaper I expected) and all the behaviors matched, so I suppose I lost track of the fact I was making assumptions. It sure does behave like an LM2576. I soldered in a real LM2596 after this was done and aside from the switching speed, all the waveforms look exactly the same. Even the snubber works the same. Again, apologies for making you angry on this.

Answer (score -1):

Snubber starts working after the loop is optimal thereby correcting inductors low quality at the purity level. 
Consider improving the *current-phase peak* within the capacitive loop (adding or substracting a couple microhenries to your equation results) before softening the output harmonics. thus driving a specific load capacitance for an instance.
Find any capacitor with the closest to zero ESR. Recoil using thiner copper or special purity copper-alloys, find 
a more specific ferrite.

Comment: Stacking of words without mutual meaning? Errr, can you clear that up? Perhaps with periods at end of sentences and capital letter at the start of the same?