# Typical flyback conductive noise emission simulaton

Tags: noise, mains, emc, flyback, ringing

I'm trying to understand what is a typical conductive noise emission of a flyback converter.

I made a simplified model (I skip the transformer replaced with a single coil - I think that this simplification does nothing to noise emission, 300 pF capacitors and 70 mH coils (having 700 mOhms serial resistance) represents normal 100 m (or something) long power line.

After I run the simulation I was surprised to see such HUGE ringing on the power line:

[image]

The amplitude is start with 170 Volts and frequency about 500 kHz:

[image]

I've never see anything like this in real world circumstances.

I suspect that my simulation model is wrong in some way. But my colleague I was able to consult with told me that it looks OK.

Any thoughts?

Comment: See similar discussion here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246301/snubbing-dcm-nonsynchronous-buck-converter/246478

Answer (score 2):

The MOSFET has capacitance between drain and source when it switches off. It forms a resonant circuit with the inductor and you get a sustained but decaying sine wave produced. This happens on all fly-back circuits.

So, if your inductor is 1 mH and your capacitor is 70 pF you will get it ringing at 600 kHz. Your MOSFET (STP8NM60) is specified as having an output capacitance of 100 pF so, not a million miles off.

Comment: What is the best practice to suppress this ringing?

Comment: I had a brief look at the data sheet and that's the number I saw but all MOSFETs are round about this figure so it shouldn't be a big surprise because all MOSFETs will do this.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to suppress it? It has to be "managed" and one way is a snubber. The snubber will prevent excessive voltages damaging the MOSFET but, still allow the ringing.

Comment: I concerned that the AC line has this kind of a noise. I didn't conduct FFT analysis yet but I suspect that this is far from being acceptable (from EMC point of view)

Comment: Some of this will get onto the AC line so increase the 100 nF capacitor to several tens or hundreds of micro farad - that would be a more normal value for this components.

Comment: Is that correct that the large capacitor will ruin the PFC?

Comment: If you are trying to design a PFC circuit then you do need to keep that capacitor low in value but maybe 100 nF is a bit too low. You might also consider making L9 and L10 coupled with a capacitor on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

- your filter is missing a bridge input shunt cap,  so your  filter is resonating in series from  the output pulse. (move C11 X-cap right)  then you have a symmetrical diff. pi filter. CLC but still missing CM Y-shunt caps to gnd.
- often each diode must shunted too to suppress parallel resonance for conducted EMI regulations. >=100pF
- its not the FETs